# Dudas de funcionamiento entre html y javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Llevo un tiempo teniendo programación informática como asignatura en el bachillerato. Hasta ahora solo hemos dado como lenguaje de programación JavaScript. Lo hacíamos mediante khan academy y era algo más bien orientado a lo visual. Hoy me he puesto a trastear un poco y he encontrado el visual studio code como nuevo entorno de desarrollo (yo había estado usando hasta ahora eclipse para aprender algo de Java de forma autodidacta). La cuestión es que al no encontrar ninguna opción en este programa para poder ver el avance de mi código (ni en consola ni de forma visual). He encontrado una forma de hacerlo, y es introducirlo dentro de un código html y verlo a través de la web.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>1er programa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script> 
ellipse(100,100,100,100);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ese es el ejemplo con el que yo he intentado probar si funcionaba. Presupongo que esto html no funcionará así ya que es un idioma que desconozco por completo. Pero me gustaría saber si puedo utilizar este método para hacer lo que yo quería (que era simplemente ver representado mi código de JavaScript, quiero decir, no estoy interesado en el html (aun)) y si no puedo, cual es la solución para poder representarlo.

Comment: no queda claro cual es la duda

Comment: La duda es que si yo abro la página de index del html, no me sale la elipse, que e slo que yo he puesto a modo de prueba para ver si funcionaba ¿por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Y ¿tengo alguna forma de probar código de javascript de forma visual sin depdender de html? esas son mis dudas

Comment: si, puedes abrir la consola del navegador presionando F12, posterior hacer lo siguiente `console.log("Hola Mundo")` lo escribes en la consola y podrás ver el resultado, es decir dentro de console.log debes pasar lo que deseas se imprima

Comment: Y si lo que quiero que se imprima es un código entero de javascript que ha hecho un dibujo a base de elipses por ejemplo?

Comment: ¿con qué fin se desea imprimir el código? ¿acaso no tienes el código en el editor/IDE?

Comment: manda a imprimir las variables por console.log o mandar a invocar la función que contiene el dibujado por medio del console.log, se necesita saber como armaste el código

Comment: Pues por ejemplo si es un código como este: https://es.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/derivado-de-proyecto-librero/4967749131862016

Comment: Quiero ver el resultado del código de esa misma forma, ya que el programa es precisamente para eso. Y si puedo ir viendo como va quedando de forma visual me puedo orientar mejor, para eso necesito imprimir el código.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo para qué «imprimir» el código. Si lo que quiere es ver el resultado en tiempo real, puede buscar en Google: «javascript hot/live reload»

Comment: Pues porque he confundido terminos y no sabía de la existencia de esas páginas, soy novato. Exacto no me refería a imprimir, sino ver el resultado en tiempo rea. Estoy buscando páginas pero solo me salen cosas de github ¿puedes darme algún nombre más concreto o enlace por favor? ah y muchas gracias por corregirlo!

Comment: Hola Alberto, creo que el problema es que estás intentando ejecutar la función `ellipse` sin hacer referencia a la librería processing.js. Esta librería implementa métodos propios (como `ellipse`, por ejemplo) y es la que se usa en khanacademy, de ahí que cuando lanzas este código en el navegador no te aparezca nada (de hecho te aparecerá un error en la consola (pulsando F12 y yendo a la pestaña "Console")). Te animo a pasarte por el chat donde te podremos resolver dudas generales sobre javascript y HTML [https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol]. Ánimo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@albertok999 bienvenido a esta comunidad, fíjate en el siguiente [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse), bastaría con hacer esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>1er programa</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script> 
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.ellipse(100, 100, 50, 75, Math.PI / 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes ver el resultado acá: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my2nwxev/). Espero te ayude.